# In Unity C# i am trying to spawn a cube at a point where a raycast hits

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to spawn a cube at the location where a raycasts hits, but the problem is that i spawn that cube at the edge of the collider that it hits. so its spawns the cube inside the other cube.
[here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJI8e.png)
This isnt for a game, im just messing around but i think its an interesting problem.

Comment: Please, **edit your question** and provide your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the hit point you can instance the cube wherever you wish, either in the hit gameobject position getting the gameobject position `goPos` (not debugged code):

```
Vector3 goPos = Vector3.zero;    
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
    if (hit.collider != null) {
        Debug.Log("hit!");
        goPos = hit.collider.gameObject;
    }
    else {
        Debug.Log("no hit");
    }
}
```

Or, the hit position itself, with `hit.point`. Check the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html)

You can draw debug elements in the scene with [OnDrawGizmos()](https://docs.unity3d.com/es/530/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDrawGizmos.html) to check if you might be changing the hit point somehow before instantiating your cube.

Also you would need to share some code to check how the hit point is obtained and the cube instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

By default object is spawn at the center point of the object if you want to spawn at a custom position you can make a empty gameObject and make the cube a child of that then you can position the parent anywhere you want and make that a prefab to instantiate.